# Eclipse: Copy/Paste not overwriting existing folders

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

Whenever I try to copy a folder within Eclipse to another destination and that destination already has a folder with the same name I don't get the option to integrate my folder into the already exisiting one. I only get the message "Element Exists in Destination" with the options "Skip", "Skip All" and "Cancel". Copying single files works as expected. It works on my computer at home but not on this one (at work). Any ideas what might causes this?
For now I overwrite files outside of Eclipse but it would be nice to know how to "fix" this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, the problem was that I was in the Package Explorer. As soon as I switched to the Project Explorer everything worked fine.

Edit:

Window->Show View->Project Explorer

If there is no project explorer you have to choose 'Other' and pick it from the list:

General->Project Explorer.